# passing dynamic array object to friend function doesn't accumulate counter

Tags: c++

I passed a dynamic array object in the 'summary' function, but i was unable to get it to accumulate the counter for a, b & c.

sample output :

Grade A : *

Grade B :

Grade C :

(only the last one is recorded, doesn't accumulate), I'm using Codeblock, and it stops working if i use pointer.)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Marks
{
    protected :
        float marks[3];
        char grade;
    public:
        void mark_entry()
        {
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Marks : ";
           cin>>marks[i];
        }
    }
    void average()
    {
        float avg = (marks[0]+marks[1]+marks[2])/3;
        set_grade(avg);
    }
    void set_grade(float average)
    {
        if(average >= 80 && average <= 100)
        {
            grade='A';
        }
        else if(average >= 50 && average < 80)
        {
            grade='B';
        }
        else if(average >= 0 && average < 50)
        {
            grade='C';
        }
    }
};
class Result :  public Marks
{
public:
    char getGrade()
    {
        return grade;
    }
    friend void summary(Result [], int);
};
void summary(Result arr[], int size)
{
    int a=0, b=0, c=0;
    cout<<"===================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"\tSummary Results"<<endl;
    cout<<"===================================="<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            switch(arr[i].grade) //switch(arr[i].getGrade)
        {
                case 'A' : a++;
                break;
                case 'B' : b++;
                break;
                case 'C' : c++;
                break;
            }
        }
    cout<<"Grade A : ";
        for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
    cout<<"\nGrade B : ";
        for(int i=0; i<b; i++)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
    cout<<"\nGrade C : ";
        for(int i=0; i<c; i++)
        {
            cout<<"*"<<endl;
        }
}
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter number of students : ";
    cin>>num;
    Result *Stud1 = new Result[num];
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        (Stud1+1)->mark_entry();
        (Stud1+1)->average();

    }
    summary(Stud1, num);
    delete[]Stud1;
}
```

Comment: You've written `Stud1+1` which is a constant, rather than `Stud1+i`. Also, you can use `Stud1[i]` instead of `(Stud1+i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in these two lines in `int main()`:

```
(Stud1+1)->mark_entry();
(Stud1+1)->average();
```

At each loop iteration, you're accessing the same element: the second one (index `1`). To access the `i`th element, just index into the array with brackets:

```
Stud1[i].mark_entry();
Stud1[i].average();
```

If you really want to add the index to the pointer like you were doing (although there is no reason to do that in this scenario), then replace `(Stud1+1)` with `(Stud1+i)`.